# Pool of photos for term extraction

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data-sets, ontologies

I need a pool of photos (if possible with description) for my project. I mainly have to perform term extraction for semantic searching. Is there something available out there that is made available for such kinds of thing?

I'm going to mine the description of these photos, maybe build ontologies and then perform search on them. The result of the mining might give useful terms about the pictures.

Comment: I know i can get image from google, I'm asking whether there is something for this, like giving pictures with their description for student to perform their project,

Comment: also, image on google are sometimes only images, i need something already with their description

Comment: What do you mean by "term extraction"? You should make your question more precise, as it stands it is hard to understand/answer.

Comment: @vonbrand, ok, edited

Comment: Are you processing the _descriptions_ (i.e., the text) or the _images_?

Comment: I need to process the text then use search techniques to test the quality of the terms extracted. The way to test is to return the images and see if the terms correlates to the images

Answer (score 1):

One good way is to use [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/). For your project you could use [available API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) for downloading photos with related information.

If you are using Java you could use the classes on [Google Codes](http://code.google.com/p/flickrdownload/).